# Obsidian Application Returning a 404 on Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I recently followed the installation guide for the Obsidian scheduler and deployed the Obsidian war file generated thereof to Apache Tomcat running on my local computer.

The application folder was generated in the webapps folder of Tomcat, and the application showed up in the list of available applications in the Tomcat Web Application Manager.

I noted, though, that the application's name (Obsidian WebApp) as specified in the web.xml file consistently fails to show up in the Display Column in the Web Application Manager. Upon trying to navigate to obsidian, I keep getting a 404 error.

I have seen in answers to similar problems that there may be an error in the web.xml file or that the index.html file referenced therein may be absent. However I cannot tell what any possible error in the web.xml could be, since I did not in any way edit it as it came with the Obsidian installation. The index.html file, too, is present as expected.

Could there be any other possible causes of this error that I may be missing? Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you visit https://obsidianscheduler.com/support/

Comment: Okay, I'll try that, thanks.